# Generic algorithm to copy image into a parallelogram, scaling, shearing, and rotating as needed

Tags: c#, image-processing, mono, bitmap

I'm trying to copy a bitmap into a parallelogram. The parallelogram can be rotated, sheared, and scaled. I'm looking for a generic algorithm that can handle this. Any programming language will work, I can translate it.

Essentially, I'm trying to clone the following method in managed code.

System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, PointF[] destPoints, RectangleF srcRect, GraphicsUnit srcUnit, ImageAttributes imageAttr);

I'm trying to make my library compatible with Mono, but the above overload isn't implemented yet.

Answer (score 3):

We want to transform a point (pixel) in euclidean 2d space. Then we must apply a transformation t :

```
pixelPos = (x, y)
transformedPixelPos = t(pixelPos)
```

Each [linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_transformation) [transformation](https://web.archive.org/web/20171221170943/http://mathforum.org/mathimages/index.php/Transformation_Matrix) (rotation, shearing, scaling) can be represented by a 2x2 [matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(math)).

**rotation**

[image]

**scaling**

[image]

**shearing**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the Graphics.TranslateTransform and ScaleTransform as well as the Transform property to achieve your goal.  There is an excellent backgrounder [available here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130312094930/http://www.bobpowell.net/transformations.htm).